# Protected destructor of policy Classes in C++

Tags: c++, templates, destructor

I wrote the following dumb policy struct:

```
template
<typename T>
struct SuperLeague
{
public:
  void printLeague(){std::cout << "SuperLegue" << std::endl;};
protected:
  //~SuperLeague(){}
};
```

and the host class

```
template
<typename TT,template <typename C> class Policy>
class League: public Policy<TT>
{
public:
  void fun()
  {
    Policy<TT>().printLeague();
  }
};
```

My main is

```
int main()
{
  League<int,SuperLeague> k;
  League<int,SuperLeague> kk;
  k.fun();
  kk.printLeague();
  League<int,SuperLeague> *kkk=new League<int,SuperLeague>();
  kkk->fun();
  //delete kkk;
};
```

Until here, everything works fine. And the output is:

```
SuperLegue
SuperLegue
SuperLegue
```

In one of his Books Andrei Alexandrescu writes:
***Unless the policy class defines a virtual destructor, applying delete to a pointer to the policy class has undefined behavior***. He explains the reasons not to use virtual destructor on the policy or protected (or private) inheritance when deriving from the policy class, and he suggests ***The lightweight, effective solution that policies should use is to define a nonvirtual protected destructor***. The problem is that when I tried to do that using `~SuperLeague(){}` the compiler complains that the destructor is protected. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be creating a temporary policy object inside `League::fun()`. Since your instance of the `League` template derives from the appropriate instance of the `Policy` template, it inherits the `printLeague()` function:

```
template
<typename TT,template <typename C> class Policy>
class League: public Policy<TT>
{
public:
  void fun()
  {
    Policy<TT>::printLeague();
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  }
};
```

The reason why your solution won't compile when you declare the destructor `protected` is that `protected` makes base class members accessible from a derived class when accessing an object (or dereferencing a reference or pointer to an object) **of the same derived class** (`League` in your case).

That is not the case in your example, where you create a temporary object of type `Policy<TT>` and invoke `printLeague()` *on that object* (which is not of type `League`).

Per paragraph 11.4/1 of the C++11 Standard:

> An additional access check beyond those described earlier in Clause 11 is applied when a non-static data
>   member or non-static member function is a protected member of its naming class (11.2). As described
>   earlier, access to a protected member is granted because the reference occurs in a friend or member of some
>   class C. If the access is to form a pointer to member (5.3.1), the nested-name-specifier shall denote C or a
>   class derived from C. All other accesses involve a (possibly implicit) object expression (5.2.5). **In this case,
>   the class of the object expression shall be C or a class derived from C**.

Answer (score 1):

```
Policy<TT>().printLeague();
```

This creates an object of type `Policy<TT>`, calls `printLeague()` on that object, then destroys the object. The compiler is complaining about destroying the object, because the destructor is protected.

Since `Policy<TT>` is a base class, just call `printLeague()` directly.